# Comma separated output based on varchar field

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have this 
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ecae7/1)

**MS SQL Server 2008 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE AccessUser
(
    AccessUserID int, 
    AccessUserName varchar(255), 
    AccessUserType int, 
    AccessUserGroups varchar(255)
);

INSERT INTO AccessUser
(   AccessUserID, 
    AccessUserName, 
    AccessUserType, 
    AccessUserGroups
)
VALUES
    (1, 'Group 1', 2, ''),
    (2, 'Group 2', 2, ''),
    (3, 'John', 5, '@1@'),
    (4, 'Nick', 5, '@1@@2@');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Empl.AccessUserName AS Name,
Firm.AccessUserName AS FirmName
FROM AccessUser AS Firm, AccessUser AS Empl
WHERE Empl.AccessUserType = 5
AND Empl.AccessUserGroups LIKE ('%@' + CAST(Firm.AccessUserID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '@%')
ORDER BY Empl.AccessUserName ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ecae7/1/0)**:

```
| NAME | FIRMNAME |
|------|----------|
| John |  Group 1 |
| Nick |  Group 1 |
| Nick |  Group 2 |
```

**QUESTION: How can i modify the Query, to output this:**

```
| NAME |      FIRMNAME      |
|------|--------------------|
| John |  Group 1           |
| Nick |  Group 1, Group 2  |
```

What I want to do is to commaseparate the Firmname, if the user has more than one `AccessUserGroups`. 
Is it even possible to do so in one query?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this way:

```
WITH CTE AS
(SELECT DISTINCT
Empl.AccessUserName AS Name,
Firm.AccessUserName AS FirmName
FROM AccessUser AS Firm, AccessUser AS Empl
WHERE Empl.AccessUserType = 5
AND Empl.AccessUserGroups LIKE ('%@' + CAST(Firm.AccessUserID AS VARCHAR(10)) + '@%'))

SELECT Name,
      FirmName = STUFF((
          SELECT ',' + convert(varchar(10),T2.FirmName)
          FROM CTE T2
          WHERE T1.Name = T2.Name
          FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM CTE T1
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY FirmName
```

Result:

```
NAME    FIRMNAME
John    Group 1
Nick    Group 1,Group 2
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5ecae7/5)</kbd>